# Single Sign On With ASP.NET Identity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net, node.js, single-sign-on, asp.net-identity

This question has been asked so many times, and a quick search came up with lot of results. But I haven’t gotten satisfactory answer yet.
We have 2 web applications ( and we may have more in future) App1 is .Net 4 Silverlight Application and App2 is Node.js/Angular application. Both applications have different domains. www.app1.com and www.app2.com The App1 is hosted in IIS and App2 is NOT in IIS

Now, we have to implement Single Sign On Feature to support these applications. I was looking into ASP.NET Identity which is available in .Net 4.5.

Questions
1.  So I thought of creating new MVC 5 application using .Net 4.5 that could serve as SSO site. If possible I wanted to use our own SQL server to maintain the credentials. But I am not sure how to share authentication ticket/cookie between sites.  I have done this before using Forms Authentication where I had to use same machine key on all websites. But those were all .net applications.  However with new identity framework and OWIN and with different types of applications i am not sure. So before I jump into it and start developing I wanted to know is it recommended approach, and if yes, can someone point me in the right direction. An article would greatly help.

2.Second options is to use Azure AD, but I am assuming we have to pay for it( we have MSDN sub) and we do not have local active directory either. Is Azure AD is the right option here? Does it work with Node.Js/Angular application. With Azure AD I guess App1 I may have to upgrade it to .Net 4.5